# Modern Books on Group Theory in German or French

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups, book-recommendation, mathematical-french

Except the book of Huppert's Group Theory I (which I have read partly), I am happy to see if there are modern books on group theory in German or French which include (one or many of) the topics on

*matrix groups, classical groups, Mathieu groups, simple groups, Coxeter groups, groups of Lie type*

and which include some recent developments in finite group theory.

Can one suggest for books?

---

**Modern**= published after Huppert's book (so after 1967/1970).

**Recent development:** some new theorems on structures of finite groups proved after say 1970.

Comment: See whether this helps you: http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/2539/books-on-group-theory-between-1885-1900

Comment: It is before 1900, I want modern means after at least 1950, or if possible 1975.

Comment: [Formes quadratiques et groupes classiques](https://www.amazon.fr/Formes-quadratiques-groupes-classiques-Deheuvels/dp/2130372074/ref=sr_1_3?s=books&ie=UTF8&qid=1482051980&sr=1-3&keywords=deheuvels) on classical groups is a good one. Although this is not a research level book.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are looking for books in German or French (your English seems fine)? It seems that most modern authors prefer to write in English to have the widest potential readerbase.

Comment: I found very less English books which contains some topics mentioned above. I am looking some other also, since different books have different flavour.

Comment: For English books: Coxeter groups are covered nicely in either Humphreys or Bjorner-Brenti. Lie type is covered well by Carter.

Comment: I agree with Tobias: I bet that for any book in either French or German dealing with your topics there are 10 or more books in English. Here are some you can check: Suzuki's "Group Theory I, II" , in particular I , Isaacs' "Finite Group Theory" , Curtis' "Matrix Groups", etc.